# Youtube video seek through jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-javascript-api

I am having a Youtube player embedded in one page and I am detecting the total seconds with `player.getDuration()` and the current seconds with `player.getCurrentTime(). I have built a jQuery slider that corresponds to the Youtube played seconds like follows:

```
   $('#progressbar').slider({
        value: 0,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        min:0,
        max:songDuration,
        animate: true,
        change: function(event, seekto){
            //We got the volume.value -> Set it to the video;
            player.seekTo(seekto.value);
        }
    });
```

where songDuration represents the total current song duration. Also on the change function seekto represents the number of seconds where to seek in the video;

Also, I am having this piece of code:

```
   setInterval(function(){
            $("#progressbar").slider({max: player.getDuration()});
            $("#progressbar").slider({value: player.getCurrentTime()});
            $('.current_elapsed').html(getPropperDuration(Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime())));
            },1000);
```

that updates the slider from start to end with the played seconds; 
The problem is that the player repeats a small portion of a second, or repeats the same seconds as the setInterval function updates the Youtube player seconds, every 1 second, and due to this, the player repeats a small fragment of a second.

Is there any workaround to use the same slider to seek in the video and also to represent the total elapsed time in the video?

Comment: a jsfiddle with a working sample would help us a bit.

Comment: @aaronfrost I will try to add a jsfiddle with a sample code to help you out. What I need to do is to have a jQuery SLIDER that will act exactly the same as the youtube player progress bar ( will need to update on video play, and I must be able to seek -- set a custom progress of the video ). Youtube player API offers me posibility to get the "progress" (second) that is played right now, the total number of seconds, and let's me set any progress (seek to any second); I just need to combine both into one jquery slider.